# What does "one [something] at a time" in the context of a pitch?

Tags: meaning-in-context

For example:

> Join us in taking design to the next level, one pixel at a time.

I usually see this kind of impression in a one-sentence pitch etc.. I believe it is used figuratively in this context, and usually means something good. Can someone help me understand what it actually means? Thanks :)

Comment: It means the same in any context, pitch or otherwise. See "one at a time" for its meaning and usage. Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

This comes from the idiom:

[**one step at a time** (FOD)](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/one+step+at+a+time)

> Slowly, carefully, and deliberately; without being careless or in a rush

It refers to doing something in its natural increments, such as...

*Eating:*

> one **bite** at a time

*Writing:*

> one **stroke** at a time

*Sewing:*

> one **stitch** at a time

In the case of your example, work is done with (probably) graphic design, and pixels are one of the smallest increments, indicating how very small the increments of the work would be.